# How to import .csv file using Pulse View?

Tags: jtag, reverse-engineering

I used an osciloscope to analize a JTAG communication, I exported the data as .csv file do that I can decode it. I'm using PulseView to do it. But I'm having problems to import the .csv file to PulseView. Below is figure with a excerpt of the file generated.

[image]

Below are the screens to configure:
[image]

I tried to remove the first line with the names of the columns, I tried to use as separator columns ';' insted ',' but it didn't wok. There are many zeros because it is the start of communication.

Please, does some one knows how to fill the fields to import the file properly  ?

**EDITED 1**

I tried again and it reads only the first line.

[image]

Comment: change the comment leader character too! (to not be ; )

Comment: Yes, Idid it. I left column format specs empty, comum separator as ';' comment leader empty.First column I put 2. I remoded the names and empty line from file and uncrecked the Get channel option. Number of logic channels I considered 6, sample rate informed by osciloscope that was 19840000Hz single column I left zero and start line 1

Comment: The timestamp seems to be formatted with a comma rather than a decimal point, which probably doesn't help.

Comment: @user_1818839 I changed the ',' to '.' but it really didn't help

Comment: Could you perhaps load your csv file?

Comment: @Syed The file became too big, I tried to split it but it still remained big. I upload it to google drive, I'll put its link here. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vyxqEUQmkTpk2TCbIBrH6qJqiCKG1viS/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Try to load it through 'Import raw binary data' and let me know if this is the data you think should have been recorded.

Comment: @Syed It does not load the file when I do  Import raw binary logic data

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/npvGT.png I can load it as raw binary data. I tried to write it out as csv. It took 50 minutes /3.2GB and hanged my computer. A csv file has commas in it not semicolons.

Comment: @Syed The oscilloscope that I use uses semicolons, not commas. So, I change it in configuration when I choose to Import csv file. But, about the figure, how you did that, you uploaded the same file I linked here? Because I tried to Import as raw binary file and Pulse View do not upload it

Comment: Choose 7 channels, 1984000 as the sample rate and zoom in using the mouse wheel. Yes i used the 200MB file you linked.

Comment: @Syed Thank you! I got it! The problem occurred after I split the file, I don't know why. But when I started not to split it anymore the problem stopped occurring and the program started to load it

Comment: Could you please say if you loaded the original file shown as 1) csv file or 2) raw data file for the benefit of others.

Comment: @Syed I loaded the original file as .csv file. The import configurations was the same way is in picture on the EDITED part of the question

Comment: I could not load the file you sent me as a CSV file using your settings. Could you load another shorter, non split file so that I can verify that it can be done?

Comment: @Syed The file has more than 2.5GB, so, I will share a slice of it. The data are all zeros because at the begninng they are all at zero state. This is the link to the file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/183eau1nOtGyhI65ngPhQdXSO1i8GXkEM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I get a 'generic unspecified error' as before.

Comment: @Syed, I downloaded the file that I linked here in my last post, I did the import configuration as it is in the first picture of the edited part of the question, and the software loaded the file correctly.

Comment: Best of luck then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was during division of the file, the file was too big and I divided it, but in someway it happened wrong. So I used the entire file and the last configuration, using semi-colon , showed in the figure above in the post, and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

try switching ; to , as data separator

Comment: No, the problem was not this. The problem was during division of the file, the file was too big and divided it, but in someway it happened wrong. So I used the entire file and the last configuration, using semi-colon , showed in the figure above in the post, and it worked. [Edited by a moderator to match the updated answer.]